# UISegmentedControl and registering callback without XIB

Tags: iphone, delegates, uisegmentedcontrol

I have added a UISegmented control as follows (this seems to work just fine, but let me know if this is a bad practice):

```
mapType = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Map", @"Satelitte", @"Hybrid", nil]];    
[_mapView addSubview:mapType];
```

Then I have a method that I would like to be called when this UISegmentedControl is changed, however, I cannot set the delegate or anything in the interface builder because I am doing this programmatically.

```
- (void)segmentedChangedType {
// some code here
}
```

How can I connect these? Thanks in advance for any help!

If the only solution is to use XIB, then I can do that, but would like to know how to do this if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured it out, you add this:

```
[mapType addTarget:self action:@selector(changeType) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: dont forget to release mapType.  Right now you have a memory leak.